# Function to determine if geo-location is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a function that determines if the users broswer is geo-location enabled and if the user has geo-location enabled it is to display a Google map, if it isn't it then displays a different map.

```
function init_maps() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoInfo, noGeoInfo, { timeout: 20000 });
  } else {
    noGeoInfo();
  }

  function geoInfo(position) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { 
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 
      var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var mapOptions = {  
        zoom: 15,       
        center: coords, 
        mapTypeControl: true, 
        navigationControlOptions:
        {
          style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions); 
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      var request = {
        origin: coords, //start point for directions
        destination: '54.861283, -6.326805', //end point for directions
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING 
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    });
    //}

    function noGeoInfo() { 
      var location = new google.maps.LatLng(54.861283, -6.326805); 
      var mapOptions = { 
        center: location, 
        zoom: 15, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
        position: location, 
        map: map 
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The function `init_maps()` is called when the user clicks on a link. The problem is that nothing is displayed in the `div` when the page loads, if I remove:

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoInfo, noGeoInfo, { timeout: 20000 });
  } else {
    noGeoInfo();
  }

  function geoInfo(position) {
```

the map then loads as expected. Why is it not being displayed if I have the `if else` to determine if geo-location is enabled?

Comment: have a look at this link: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-use-geolocation-api-with-google-maps  it has a demo at the bottom using `if (navigator.geolocation) {` and demonstrates its usage properly

Comment: This might help: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation